# Specify column separator for BCP

Tags: bcp

How do I specify column separator with "," for bcp or this code below

```
bcp [wwtest].[accesscontrol].[Roles] out C:\test\bcp_outputTable.csv -SPC01 -T -c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding -t,  .  See following documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The command lines below illustrate how to export data using a comma (,) or vertical pipe (|) as a field separator:

Export using comma:

```
BCP [Database].[Schema].[Table] out C:\FOLDERNAME\FILENAME.DAT -c -t, -S SERVERNAME -T
```

Export using vertical pipe:

```
BCP [Database].[Schema].[Table] out C:\FOLDERNAME\FILENAME.DAT -c -t^| -S SERVERNAME -T
```

The vertical pipe is different because it must be escaped. Quoting -t| will not work.
I hope this helps.

Please note command line switches are case sensitive.